# Faixa de números aleatórios em C

Tags: c, random

Em um certo programa, preciso gerar um valor aleatório maior que 1000 (com um limite definido por mim para até 5000 (talvez ainda seja um valor muito elevado)). Este código único é referente a um tipo de cadastro a ser realizado. Após sanar algumas dúvidas do `rand() %` com um professor, chegamos a este código: `1000 + rand() % rand()`.

Seria suficiente para o que eu quero? E como eu poderia delimitá-lo para até 5000? Esta sendo a única parte que eu não consegui implementar.

Comment: Acho que deveria ser `1000 + rand() % 4000` mas não testei.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A função [`rand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand) gera números pseudo-aleatórios entre 0 e (possivelmente) 32767 (dependendo de implementação pode ter maior amplitude).

```
1001 + ( rand() % 4000 ) //os parenteses estão aí só para deixar a precedência mais visível
```

Você diz que precisa de número acima de 1000, então o menor número possível que a expressão deve gerar é 1001. Como a função `rand()` tem como valor menor o zero, basta somar 1001 para alcançar o limite inferior considerando que estamos falando de números inteiros.

Para garantir que não venha nenhum número fora da faixa, dividimos o resultado da função pela quantidade de elementos possíveis na faixa. Se vai de 1001 à 5000, temos 4000 números possíveis na faixa desejada. Assim a divisão por 4000 pegará de 0 à 3999 inclusive.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/vZwGhW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hdcltwqr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/RandomRange.c).

Comment: Entendi melhor agora como o funcionamento do rand() funciona, e sua explicação foi mais do que excelente. Obrigado! :)

Comment: mas o problema dessa função que por mais que ela seja aleatória, ela retorna sempre a mesma sequencia

Comment: @Joannis concordo mas aí é só adaptar para usar a hora, deixei quase pronto. Depois eu edito p/ ficar do jeito que deseja.

Comment: eu ja fiz, se quiser pode colar mminha resposta na sua!

Comment: o importante é ajudar ele =D

Answer (score 7):

***Complemento da resposta do @Maniero***

**A função** `void srand (unsigned int seed)`

- Cada elemento de uma sequência pseudo-aleatória é gerado a partir do elemento anterior.
- Como pode ser desejável repetir uma sequência pseudo-aleatórios em C sempre usa o mesmo primeiro elemento.
- A função `void srand (unsigned int seed)` permite variar esse primeiro elemento, que serve como semente da sequência.

***Usando o relógio como semente***

- A biblioteca time possui uma função time cujo resultado é um número de segundos transcorridos desde um momento fixado (00:00:00 UTC de 1 de janeiro de 1970).
- Esse número pode ser usado como `seed` na chamada de `srand` para gerar uma semente variável e imprevisível.

  - O resultado de `time` tem um tipo `time_t` e deve ser convertido em `unsigned int` para que possa ser usado como argumento para `srand`.
  - A função `time` também requer um argumento que ao efeito dessa aplicação pode ser passado como `null`
  - `srando((unsigned) time(NULL))`

Exemplo:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int numero_randomico;
   srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
   numero_randomico = 1001+(rand())%4000;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Para gerar valores inteiros aleatórios em C no intervalo `[a, b)`:

```
a + rand() % (b - a)
```

Por exemplo, `x % 5` pode ser um dos valores `0, 1, 2, 3` ou `4`. Então, quando fazemos `rand() % (b - a)` vamos gerar um numero entre `0` e `b - a - 1`.

Representando por intervalos:

```
[0, b - a - 1]
```

Agora, se você somar `a` a ambos os extremos do intervalo:

```
[a, b - 1]
```

Que e o intervalo que você quer (talvez tomando cuidado para inserir o `1` no extremo direito).