# Gerar número aleatório entre -99 e 99

Tags: c, números-aleatórios

Estou com certa dificuldade aqui no meu código que é o seguinte, eu sei que para gerar números aleatórios entre `0` e `9` é - `x = rand() % 10`.

Então agora eu queria gerar números entre `-99` e `99`, e fiz assim da seguinte maneira  - `x = (rand()%200)-100`, o problema é que nos números negativos ele gera o número `-100`, e nos positivos só gera mesmo até o `99`, como é o pretendido.

Como devo fazer para gerar a partir do `-99` e não do `-100`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seu problema é que o intervalo `[0,200[` tem `200` elementos, mas o intervalo `[-99,99]` tem só `199` elementos. Sugiro gerar o intervalo `[0,199[` e então deslocá-lo negativamente para `[-99,100[`:

```
x = (rand()%199)-99
```

Para mais detalhes, ver [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39220/215) a uma [pergunta similar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39215/215).

Comment: Ah sim entendi, agora deu certo. Valeuuu!