# Geração de números aleátorios

Tags: c, random

Declarei um método para gerar números aleatórios, mas os resultados são quase sempre os mesmos, por que?

```
int geraAleatorio(int min, int max) {

    return ((rand() % (max - min)) + min) + 1;
}
```

Existe algum outro algoritmo?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Faltou inicializar a semente aleatória. O gerador aleatório não é aleatório de fato então você precisa randomizar a semente, o mais comum é usar o relógio do computador.

Só deve chamar o [`srand()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) uma vez na aplicação com o mesmo argumento. Senão ele gera o mesmo número.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int geraAleatorio(int min, int max) {
    return ((rand() % (max - min)) + min) + 1;
}

int main(void) {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    printf("%d\n", geraAleatorio(10, 20));
    printf("%d\n", geraAleatorio(10, 20));
    printf("%d\n", geraAleatorio(30, 40));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/DvgBiQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dxwqzlsw-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Library/RandSeed.c).

Comment: Não era essa o problema.

Comment: @hello É o que você colocou na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar essa linha antes de chamar a função:

```
srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
```

Dê uma olhada nesse post antigo irá te ajudar [Faixa de números aleatórios em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39215/faixa-de-n%C3%BAmeros-aleat%C3%B3rios-em-c)