# Armazenar números aleatórios em uma variável em C

Tags: c

Olá, preciso comparar o valor aleatório de 2 dados lançados, e gostaria de saber como eu consigo armazenazeno o resultado desses números nas variáveis d1 e d2.

```
int d1, d2, n;

printf("Quantas vezes voce deseja jogar? ");
scanf("%d",&n);


for (int contador = 0; contador < n; contador++){
    printf("%d \n",rand() % 6);
    printf("%d \n",rand() & 6);

    if (d1 == d2){
        printf("Os dados deram iguais \n");
    } else if(d1 > d2){
        printf("D1 venceu \n");
    } else{
        printf("D2 venceu \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Para gerar números com algum grau de aleatoriedade convém inicializar a semente com a função `srand`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em vez de imprimir diretamente os valores da função `rand()`, atribua os valores às variáveis `d1` e `d2`.

Conforme cita Deitel, em seu [livro](https://www.amazon.com.br/C-como-programar-Paul-Deitel/dp/8576059347), ao utilizar a função [srand()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39443/110782) se desejamos randomizar sem necessidade de fornecer uma semente a cada vez, podemos usar um comando, como:

```
srand(time(0));
```

Seu código ficará assim:

```
int main()
{
int d1, d2, n;

printf("Quantas vezes voce deseja jogar? ");
scanf("%d",&n);
srand( time(0));

for (int contador = 0; contador < n; contador++){
    d1 =  rand() % 6;
    d2 = rand() & 6;
    printf("%d \n",d1);
    printf("%d \n",d2);

    if (d1 == d2){
        printf("Os dados deram iguais \n");
    } else if(d1 > d2){
        printf("D1 venceu \n");
    } else{
        printf("D2 venceu \n");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Eu já fiz isso mas a medida que eu digito o valor de n, ele sempre repete a sequência de números aleatórios. Por exemplo se eu digito n = 2 o programa retorna 5 5 4 4, e sempre fica com esses valores.

Comment: @MatheusSantos teste agora, veja se funciona

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora ele está gerando os números de forma aleatória.